# How to get permission with a description?

Tags: ionic-framework, permissions, ionic3, ionic4

I found on an application that asks permission to use bluetooth with a description of why this is needed. I need to implement this in my application.

[image: n]

How to name this function? How can this be done on ionic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This BT request would have to be triggered via a cordova plugin, eg this one for iOS: 
https://github.com/swetha-thoomoju/cordova-plugin-ios-bluetooth-permissions

..or by editing cordova's config.xml to include:

```
<config-file parent="NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
    <string>Improve location accuracy when finding nearby services</string>
</config-file>
```

The above is only for iOS, but I'm pretty sure something exists for Android as well.